# How can I differentiate this equation? $y = \sqrt[4]{\frac{(x^3+2\sqrt{x})^2(x-sinx)^5}{(e^{-2x}+3x)^3}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$y = \sqrt[4]{\frac{(x^3+2\sqrt{x})^2(x-sinx)^5}{(e^{-2x}+3x)^3}}$

I tried removing the root but that got me no where

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**:  First try differentiate $\ln y.$

Comment: And if I don't use your hint, I should probably die before ending !

Answer (score 0):

Where are you getting stuck exactly? Removing the root would look like a good first step to me. The equation doesn't look particularly difficult, just big.

Answer (score 0):

the solution of the given problem should be this here
$$\frac{\left(x^3+2 \sqrt{x}\right) (x-\sin (x))^4 \left(-3 \left(3-2 e^{-2
   x}\right) \left(x^3+2 \sqrt{x}\right) (x-\sin (x))+5 \left(3 x+e^{-2 x}\right)
   \left(x^3+2 \sqrt{x}\right) (1-\cos (x))+2 \left(3 x+e^{-2 x}\right) \left(3
   x^2+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right) (x-\sin (x))\right)}{4 \left(3 x+e^{-2
   x}\right)^4 \left(\frac{\left(x^3+2 \sqrt{x}\right)^2 (x-\sin (x))^5}{\left(3
   x+e^{-2 x}\right)^3}\right)^{3/4}}$$